# Rails 3 - save few models which belongs to each other by nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I can't get how to do one thing. I have models **User**, **Teacher**, **TeacherEducation**. **TeacherEducation** belongs to **Teacher**, **Teacher** belongs to **User**. I would like to save **User**, **Teacher** and **TeacherEducation** in one line by `user.save` in my controller. Is that possible? If no then which is better way to save that?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...,
                  :teacher_attributes
  has_one :teacher
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher 
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  has_one :teacher_education
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :teacher_education
end

class TeacherEducation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

Right now without TeacherEducation i have such view

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_teacher_url, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    <%= f.fields_for :teacher do |builder| %>
    # Fields of teacher
    <% end %>
    # Fields of user
<% end %>
```

My controller

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def new_teacher
    @user = User.new
    teacher = @user.build_teacher
    ...
  end

  def create_teacher   
    user = User.new( params[:user] )

    if user.save
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I think..

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => create_teacher_url, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <%= field_set_tag do %>
    <%= f.fields_for :teacher do |builder| %>
      # Fields of teacher
      <%= builder.fields_for :teacher_education do |edu_fields| %>
        # Fields of teacher_education
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    # Fields of user
<% end %>
```